# Как использовать нерекомендуемые компоненты в планировщике заданий?

Tags: windows, администрирование, планировщик-задач

В планировщике заданий во время добавления нового задания, помимо открытия приложения, имеются функции *вывода сообщений* и *отправки e-mail'а*.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При выборе одной из них выскакивает уведомление, мол, **ошибка : выбран нерекомендуемый компонент**.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем встаёт вполне логичный вопрос: зачем они там нужны, и можно ли обойти это назойливое уведомление, всё-таки использовав, допустим, вывод сообщения?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Они не рекомендованы потому, как устарели. ЕМНИП, на нашем англо-французском ноутбуке этот термин звучит как 'obsolète' - устаревший. Это не значит, что ими нельзя пользоваться, но стоит от этого отказаться, так как компонент может исчезнуть даже в следующем обновлении, либо испытывает определенные проблемы с окружением, либо потенциально небезопасен. К тому же, если не ошибаюсь, использование таких компонентов приводит к лишним строкам в журналах Windows, а их и так разбирать - не сахар :)
Поэтому стоит переключиться на более современные программы и скрипты.

Отправить почту можно с помощью Powershell:

```
Send-MailMessage -From 'Vasja <vasja@pupkin.com>' -To 'Petja <petja@microsoft.com>' -Subject 'Всё пропало, шеф! :)'
```

Вывести сообщение с помощью msg:

```
msg Petja Всё пропало, шеф!
```